# How to get rid of: "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '...' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)"?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to display an image from my phone in my Flutter app and getting following error:

```
Another exception was thrown: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1570277797774' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

I don't understand the `Permission denied` part, because I added...

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

...to my `android/app/src/mainAndroidManifest.xml` file, and when running the app it shows that it really does have the permissions to read files:
[image: Permissions]
Also the file I'm trying to open exists and seems fine - I can open it with other apps as well:
[image: File to open]
Here's my Code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(FileOps());

class FileOps extends StatefulWidget {
  _FileOpsState createState() => _FileOpsState();
}

class _FileOpsState extends State<FileOps> {
  File localFile;
  String widgetTitle = 'Show Image';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    localfile.then((File _localFile) {
      setState(() {
        localFile = _localFile;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widgetTitle,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widgetTitle),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.file(localFile),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<File> get localfile async {
    String imgPath =
        '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1570277797774';
    return File(imgPath);
  }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
name: template_app
description: A template Flutter app for testing and minimal examples

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

> Answers to questions in comments:
>
> - "com.android.providers.media" is not the name of my app, idk what it is - but the image I want to open is there
> - My Android Version is 8.0.0, my phone is also running EMUI 8.0.0 (idk what it is exactly, some Huawei stuff)
> - I can open the file with the standard app that came with the phone called "Gallery"

Comment: `com.android.providers.media` ? Is that your app?

Comment: Are you on Android Q?

Comment: `I can open it with other apps as well:`  Which other apps? Or only the systems Files app?

Comment: @blackapps thx 4 the questions, I answered them on the bottom of my question, if anything's still unclear, let me know :)

Comment: Take a file manager app. Browse to that directory and check if the file names are the same.

Comment: You could also yourself try to list the files in that directory. You ask  the user at runtime to confirm the permissions mentioned in manifest?

Comment: @blackapps the second screenshot is actually made in my file manager app - it seems to be the correct name. I tried to list all files in the directory, but got a permission error again: `Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/' (OS Error: Permission
I/flutter (27386): denied, errno = 13)`

Comment: @blackapps I just do what you can see in my code - during the installation I see the permissions needed like in the 1st screenshot. I don't see any additional popups for permission confirmation. Can I force it somehow?

Comment: So you have not added code to ask the user at runtime to confirm those requested permissions?

Comment: How is it possible that you can do it with your file manager app and not with this one?

Comment: @blackapps all code I have you can see in my question - I think you brought me on the right track, thanks - I noticed that indeed the permission are missing. When I turn them on in the settings for this app it works. So now I just have to figure out how to ask the user at runtime to confirm the permissions, instead of having to do this manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Attention: My answer is a bit old now, I heard that a newer version of `permission_handler` works a bit differently now - so just google how it works nowadays, I guess.

I got it - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` seemed to only define what permissions were needed, but not actually requesting them :D
So I manually requested the permissions and then everything worked:

I followed [this tutorial](https://codinglatte.com/posts/flutter/handling-requesting-for-permissions-like-a-pro-in-flutter/).

1. I added `permission_handler:` to `pubspec.yaml`
2. Changed my `get localfile` get method to:

```dart
  Future<File> get localfile async {
    final PermissionHandler _permissionHandler = PermissionHandler();
    var result = await _permissionHandler.requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
    if (result[PermissionGroup.storage] == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      // permission was granted
      String imgPath = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1570277797774';
      return File(imgPath);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would also suggest adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application.../>` tag to cater for `Android Q` and above.

Comment: @Pierre Buddy, you really save my day. I was having issue in one of the production app where an integrated android scan module was not able to save file. Not to the flutter project but adding this tag to scan android module fix my issue. So many 

Answer (score 5):

What Worked for me is

First in android/app/build.gradle

- set your compileSdkVersion to 29 (current highest)
- set your targetSdkVersion to 29 (current highest)

Secondly in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

- add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true to the  tag

Then rebuild and see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

i got rid of this error by executing
`flutter clean && flutter pub get` in the terminal

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting the code editor and the emulator if the external files changes may be slow message is displayed on your android studio. And then run flutter clean followed by pub get.

Doing this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What i did when i faced the problem is i closed the editor and re-opened it after that i run the following commands sequentially before build in android studio.

1: `flutter clean`

2: `flutter pub get`