# Isar Database - Access denied by Windows. Cannot open file, path = '\isar.dll'

Tags: flutter, dart, windowserror, flutter-isar, filesystemexception

I am trying to run CRUD tests in Flutter application. The local database that I am using is Isar database. It seems that application does not have rights to use Isar in Windows.
However, example test runs smoothly with MacOS.
Does anyone have had a similiar problem?

Test file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pill_cabinet/layers/data/models/reminder.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

// Helper Methods for configuring the tests

String? testTempPath;

String getRandomName() {
  var random = Random().nextInt(pow(2, 32) as int).toString();
  return '${random}_tmp';
}

Future<Isar> openTempIsar(List<CollectionSchema<dynamic>> schemas,
    {String? name}) async {
  final dartToolDir = path.join(Directory.current.path, '.dart_tool');
  testTempPath = path.join(dartToolDir, 'test', 'tmp');
  return Isar.open(
    schemas: schemas,
    name: name ?? getRandomName(),
    directory: kIsWeb ? '' : testTempPath!,
  );
}

void main() {
  group('Isar Experiment', () {
    late Isar isar;

    setUp(() async {
      await Isar.initializeIsarCore(download: true);
      isar = await openTempIsar(
        [ReminderSchema],
      );
    });

    test('Isar Test', () {
      assert(1 == 1);
    });

    tearDown(() {
      isar.close(deleteFromDisk: true);
    });
  });
}
```

The main error:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '\isar.dll' (OS Error: Access denied.
, errno = 5)
```

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH49N.png)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946720/14957991

Comment: Yes, did not have an effect on the problem but thx